# ModelForm with foreignkey field is not being saved

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I'm trying to save a ModelForm with foreignkey field from another model. But somehow the data is not being saved. 
The primary key of the foreignkey field in the Problem models is from Biodata models
index.html form is loaded with session['patient'] value that should be the value of the foreignkey in the Problem models upon creation of new item. 
Upon submitting the form, it says the new item is successfully added, but at the backend, it wasn't saved at all.

Here's the code :

**models.py**

```
class Biodata(models.Model):
  lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  dob = models.DateField()
  sex = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
  suburb = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=True)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
  postcode = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname

class Problems(models.Model):
  biodata = models.ForeignKey(Biodata, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=None)
  problem = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  notes = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  date = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def __str__(self):
    return self.problem
```

**views.py**

```
def problem_add(request):
  patient_id = request.session['patient']

  form = ProblemForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
     instance = form.save(commit=False)
     instance.Biodata = Biodata.objects.get(id=patient_id)
     instance.save
     messages.success(request,('Problem added'))
     return redirect('/crud/index/')
  else : 
     messages.success(request,('There is error in the form'))
  return redirect('/crud/index/')
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProblemForm(forms.ModelForm):

STATUS = [('S','Stable'),('U','Unstable'),('I','Inactive'),('O','Ongoing Dx.')]

problem = forms.CharField(label='',max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Problem'}))
notes = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4,'placeholder':'Notes'}))
status = forms.ChoiceField(label='', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'placeholder':'Status'}), choices=STATUS)
date = forms.DateField(label='', widget=forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y', attrs={'class':'datepicker','placeholder':'Date'}),
    input_formats=('%m/%d/%Y', ))
class Meta :
    model = Problems
    fields = ('problem','notes','status','date')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py correct it

```
instance.biodata=Biodata.objects.get(id=patient_id)
```

You are trying

```
instance.Biodata = .......
```

Since Biodata field does not exist in Problems table

Comment: Check in your views, if request.method=='POST': and your post logic

Answer (score 0):

You have just written `instance.save` and this doesn't result in any error because it is valid to write it like that. The execution moves to new line and you get the success message.

Because `save` is a method on instance you should call it like `instance.save()`.